# Query a collection to check if one map object exists and other doesn't exist on in firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to find a simple query where will be able to get all the documents where one map object property exists and one map object property doesn't exist. How can I do that

Here is the document on which I want to query. Basically, I want to query the collection where these conditions meet

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to query documents where `subscriptionData` field exists? Also can you explain "one map object property doesn't exist" ?

Comment: I want to query for documents where ```subscriptionData``` doesn't exist and ```userContributionData``` exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there isn't any way to query documents based on existence of a field.

One work around is to use `orderBy("userContributionData")` in your query which will return documents where this field exists and then manually removing documents where `subscriptionData` field is missing.

Another way would be set default value of the field to `null` so you can use a `where('field', '==', null)` clause.